# Unable to run application with Gradle: Error: Could not find or load main class 1.8

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-idea2017

I am using IntelliJ Idea 2017.3 and on any Gradle project (even for simple 'hello world' from GitHub) I always got next error:

```
"Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/3.5-rc-2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error: Could not find or load main class 1.8"
```

Meanwhile, if I run an application with Gradle wrapper (gradlew.bat in my case) everything works perfectly. For me it looks like misconfiguration issue, but I cannot find what I am doing wrongly in Idea configuration or any other place. I appreciate any help with it or clue where to dig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved and I would like to share this knowledge with all those who encounter a similar problem.
In my case, I had to delete two configuration files **gradle.experimental.xml** and **gradle.settings.xml** from IDEA configuration directory **%IDEA_HOME%\config\options**. I suppose they were created at the time when I installed Gradle globally on my PC. Somehow these settings were persisted, even after I removed globally installed Gradle and started to use  Gradle's wrapper.